# Fluent NHibernate, Many-to-Many, setting a property on the child from the many-to-many table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a `Subscriber` object that contains a list of `Provider` objects.  Providers can belong to many Subscribers, hence the many-to-many relationship.  This is fine, except that the `Provider` needs to define a `Status` property but this cannot be stored in the `Provider` table, as the same provider could have a different `Status` for different Subscribers, so I am storing the `Status` in the many-to-many table.  At the moment I have a basic many-to-many mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(s => s.Providers)
    .Table("SubscriberProviders")
    .ParentKeyColumn("SubscriberID")
    .ChildKeyColumn("ProviderID");
```

How can I set the `Status` property, of the `Provider`, within the many-to-many mapping?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `many-to-many` mapping can't have properties of its own, so you have to map the join table into an artificial **ProviderSubscriber** entity, which will be `one-to-many` from the Provider.

For a full example of a workaround, see [Many-to-many relationships with properties](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2010/12/many-to-many-relationships-with.html)

Comment: Thanks Diego, I actually ended up doing this before I saw your post.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to map the cross-reference table (which NH currently generates for you), and change the mapping between Providers and Subscribers to instead be a HasMany() on either side referencing the cross-reference table.